# How many dense layers is enough?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm pretty new to NNs so sorry if the following is a silly question but:
Is it helpful to stack multiple Keras dense layers on each other?

I am familiar with the universal approximation theorem. But I would expect that the answer isn't that simple as: *when using dense layers use only one layer because it is enough to approximate whatever you need*.

I was thinking that using more layers might result in multiple smaller layers, thus decrease the number of params. Or that it could boost performance.

Could you please explain how many dense layers are typically used and give some intuition on why smaller or larger number of layers is a good choice?

EDIT: When talking about *one layer* I meant one hidden layer. We can see it as having an MLP with input, hidden and output layer.

Comment: I would experiment to permute these parms to discover sweet spots ... more layers gives a higher dimensional parameter space so ability to evolve into more subtle solutions so is optimum num of layers simply a function of having enough while limiting num due to efficiency

Comment: Yes, yes. I did some experiments on few datasets and my intuition from it is that 1-2 hidden layers is enough and more wont help. But at the same time I might be missing something important not sure.